# PHP in FastCGI mode won't read .user.ini directives

Tags: php, configuration-files, ini, fpm

I have a setup which runs PHP 7.2 via FPM, proxied by nginx (OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS).

### The problem

I put `.user.ini` in the document root folder right next to the `index.php`.
The contents of the file:

```
auto_append_file="./autoAppend.php"
```

The file `autoAppend.php` is in place in the same directory.
But when I read the settings directive `auto_append_file` from index.php during runtime it returns an empty string and the actual file is not appended when index.php is executed.

This directive `auto_append_file` must be changeable in `.user.ini` file since [it has](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) `PHP_INI_PERDIR` flag.

### Current settings

Here are my INI settings read in runtime from within the index.php:

- `user_ini.filename`:`.user.ini`
- `user_ini.cache_ttl`:`10`
- `auto_append_file`:`""`
- `php_sapi_name()`:`fpm-fcgi`

Here are settings in FPM's php.ini:

```
; Automatically add files after PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-append-file
auto_append_file =
```

How do I make PHP to read and apply directives from `.user.ini` file?

Comment: https://websistent.com/php-auto_prepend_file-and-auto_append_file/ found this